# jQuery Autocomplete From MySQL Result (No JSON - If Possible)

Tags: jquery, mysql

I need to have autocomplete feature on my website, but I'm not JSON-guy. I never dealing with JSON so I hope I still can have autocomplete from plain MySQL result.

but from what I saw here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ I don't see any possibilities to get autocomplete from MySQL result. is it true?

Comment: which scripting language you are using for backend?

Comment: I'm using PHP. do you have some example of this autocomplete?

Comment: Reffer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305294/jquery-autocomplete-mysql-php

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use php also

[check here](http://www.mix26.com/demo/ajax-autocomplete/test.php)

this is ajax demo :)

[download](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzB2od8c0umkZGE2ZDA2MzctMjA3Mi00YmJlLWExNTMtMzY5OGVhNDAxNzlh/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make an AJAX call and take the search results then send them back as JSON to the client side.Then just bind it with the AutoComplete Textbox.

The jQuery plgin to be used is http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete

```
Example- A textbox with ID 'txtlocation' is added with autocomplete functionality here.
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#txtlocation").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PublicHome/AutoPopulateLocation", //Call to Server Side 
            data: "{ 'searchText': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.Suburb 

                    }))
                },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({
            "width": 344,
            "font-size": 11,
            "font-family": "Arial"
        });
      }
   });


});
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong : url: "/PublicHome/AutoPopulateLocation", //Call to Server Side >> means I have to refer to my php file like this url: "search.php" and what that search.php does is actually convert MySQL output into JSON format, is that what you mean?

Comment: and what 'search text' on this line data: "{ 'searchText': '" + request.term + "' }", refers to?